# foreach 文でのコンパイルエラー

Tags: scala, playframework

標題の件についての質問です。

playframework + slick を使っていて、どうしてもコンパイルエラーとなってしまいます。

コメントしてある箇所の
Ok(Json.obj("contracted" -> false))
をいれればコンパイルは通りますが、
Ok(Json.obj("contracted" -> true))
が適用されずに出力される値が一律
Ok(Json.obj("contracted" -> false))
となってしまいます。

質問者はjavaについては多少の知識がありますが、
scala、playframework、slickなどは初めての技術です。
質問者の力が未熟で質問の仕方にも問題があるかもしれませんが、
どうかご教授いただけると助かります。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※追記です：処理の分岐を一度、文字列型で受け取ることでコンパイルエラーを回避することができました。
もしもっと良い方法などがあればご教授お願いします。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

※さらに追記です：この方法だと、sの型が
(Option[Byte], Option[Byte])のときにだけ可能でした。
Seq[(Option[Byte], Option[Byte])]の場合にはやはりうまく対応できないようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Action.async`に与えるブロックは`Future[Result]`を返さないといけません。
`Seq.foreach`は`Unit`を返すため、型が`Future[Unit]`になっていると思います。

元のコードからは、どのような時にどのような値をを返したいのか、読み取れませんが…

```
repo.getRoomStatus(roomNumber, client_id).map {
    case Seq() => Ok(Json.obj("contracted" -> false))
    case _ => Ok(Json.obj("contracted" -> true))
}
```

とか

```
repo.getRoomStatus(roomNumber, client_id).map { s =>
  if(s.exists(t => t._1.isDefined && t._2.isDefined))
    Ok(Json.obj("message" -> "valid data."))
  else
    BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "invalid data."))
}
```

とか

Comment: お返事が遅くなり大変申しわけありません。
また質問の意図がわかりにくいものであったにも関わらず、ご回答を寄せていただいてありがとうございます。

> `Action.async`に与えるブロックは`Future[Result]`を返さないといけません。
`Seq.foreach`は`Unit`を返すため、型が`Future[Unit]`になっていると思います。

まずここの部分でなぜ自分のforeachがコンパイルエラーであったのかを理解することができました。
感謝いたします。

次にsの型がSeq[(scala.Option[Byte], scala.Option[Byte])]
であるため、ループを回して中の要素を検証する必要があったのですが、
そちらに対しては下記のような簡潔な記述でこちらの意図を汲み取っていただきました。

    if(s.exists(t => t._1.isDefined && t._2.isDefined))

求めていた情報を返していただきありがとうございました。
もし機会がありましたらまたご教授願えると助かります。